# how to mix a decision of with an observer and synced actions? (Angular)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular

I have six square views in my project, I have to options to click on them:

1. click on one and and it get selected with some css fade color on top of it to show its selected. this already works.
2. select couple of them and having the same css fade color to show the squares are selected. this works to some degree but messed with something else.

so to recognize which mode im at I have radio buttom that call `multipleSelectionMode`.

so this is the code:

this is my square component html file.

```
  <div *ngIf="oneChoosed" layout="row" layout-align="center center" class="one-chose">
  </div>


  <div *ngIf="multipleChoosed" layout="row" layout-align="center center" class="omult-chose">
  </div>
```

in this component class I have 2 inputs I get from the main screen component:

```
@Input() oneChoosed: boolean;
@Input() multipleChoosed: boolean;
```

this is have I update this inputs from the main screen component html file:

```
[oneChoosed]="isOneChoosed(squares)"
[multipleChoosed]="isMultipleChoosed(squares)"
```

and in the main screen component class I get the click events and the id's of the squares, it looks like this:

```
export class mainScreenComp implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  multipleSelectionMode: Observable<boolean>;
  oneChoosenIds: string[];
  multipleChosenIds: string[];
  _oneChoseSquareIdsSubscription: Subscription;
  _multipleChoseSquaresIdsSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.multipleSelectionMode = this.brainComp.curSelectionTyp.map(selecType => selecType === SelectionType.multiple);
this._oneChoseSquareIdsSubscription = this.brainComp.choosingOption.subscribe(
  (chos: ChoosingOption) => {
    switch (chos.option) {
      case ChoosingOption.oneChose:
        this.oneChoosenIds = chos.chosedIds.squares;
        break;
      case ChoosingOption.finishedOneSel:
        this.oneChoosenIds = undefined;
        break;
    }
  }
);


this._multipleChoseSquaresIdsSubscription = this.brainComp.choosingOption.subscribe(
  (chos: Chosed) => {
    this.multipleChosenIds = chos.squares;
  }
);
```

}

```
isOneChoosed(square: SquaresIQ): boolean {
    return (this.oneChoosenIds ? this.oneChoosenIds.includes(square.squareId) : false);
  }


  isMultipleChoosed(square: SquaresIQ): boolean {
    return (this.multipleChosenIds ? this.multipleChosenIds.includes(square.squareId) : false);
  }
```

so basically I add squares id's to the arrays oneChoosenIds and multipleChosenIds and check if they empty or not to decide what to return,

this works, BUT, when im in oneChoosing state where I can 
only choose one, when I click on it I see both css square covers that shows that the square is selected...cause they have different design I can notice it.

so it means this *ngIf="oneChoosed" and this *ngIf="multipleChoosed" both returned true...so I thought to put extra condition with my observer `multipleSelectionMode` in the _multipleChoseSquaresIdsSubscription subscription, but this is async cause its an observer and the other actions are sync so its not working properly. do you have a suggestion for me to solve it?

Comment: I don't know the answer but if you would make the core part of your question more prominent others are more likely to chime in. If seems what the question is all about "How to derive a state from two observables", right? If this is the case, IMHO the other content of your question mostly adds confusion.